# Discord.js V12, I need to split a message embed in two and send them if it exceeds the max character limit, how would I do so?

Tags: javascript, split, discord, discord.js

So, as stated in the title I want to split a rich embed message in two AND send them if it exceeds the max character limit on discord. Here is what I have attempted, but it does not work:

```
for (let i = 0; i < Info.length; i += 2000) {
    const toSend = Info.substring(i, Math.min(Info.length, i + 2000));
    const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Information:')
        .setDescription(toSend)
        .setColor('#000000');

    message.channel.send(Embed)   
        .catch(console.error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [`Util.SplitMessage()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Util?scrollTo=s-splitMessage) method like so:

## Version 12

```js
   const { MessageEmbed, Util } = require("discord.js");
   let y = await Util.splitMessage(toSend, { maxLength: 2000 });
   const x = new MessageEmbed()
   x.setDescription(y);
   message.channel.send(x);
```

## Version 13

```js
   const { MessageEmbed, Util } = require("discord.js");
   let y = await Util.splitMessage(toSend, { maxLength: 2000 });
   const x = new MessageEmbed()
   x.setDescription(y)
   message.channel.send({ embeds: [x]});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can combine the informations with more than 1 field, or put the information in the description.
LIMITS:
Embed titles are limited to 256 characters,
Embed descriptions are limited to 2048 characters,
There can be up to 25 fields,
A field's name is limited to 256 characters and its value to 1024 characters,
The footer text is limited to 2048 characters,
The author name is limited to 256 characters,
The sum of all characters from all embed structures in a message must not exceed 6000 characters,
A bot can have one embed per message,
A webhook can have ten embeds per message,

Comment: I'm aware, but that doesn't answer my question or help me. That is the reason to why I want to send more than one embed if it exceeds 2000 characters, because the limit on a description is 2048.